# Assume A is a set and define $\alpha$ to be the set of ordinals dominated by A. Show that (iii) $\alpha$ is the least cardinal greater than card A.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I said: We know that a cardinal is the least ordinal equinumerous to A. We know $\alpha$ is equinumerous to $\bigcup$A, and so $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of A. Thus $\alpha$ is the least ordinal equinumerous to $\bigcup$A and thus $\alpha$ is the least cardinal greater than card(A).

Is my reasoning correct? If not, could you give me a hint for approaching this question?

Comment: Except for the first sentence (the definition of the cardinality of $A$), the remainder of this argument is wrong. $\alpha$ need not be equinumerous to $\bigcup A$. Since $A$ needn't consist of ordinals, "least upper bound of $A$" isn't defined. And even if $\alpha$ happened to be the least ordinal equinumerous to $\bigcup A$, that wouldn't necessarily imply that it's the least cardinal greater than the cardinality of $A$.

Comment: Perhaps spell out what it explicitly means for an ordinal $\beta$ to be dominated by $A$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That means there exists an one-to-one function from $\beta$ to A. Can you give me a hint as to how I can proceed from there?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see. Do you have any suggestions to approach this question?